# What is the largest, compact connected-network polyomino for these tiles?

Tags: visual, polyomino, network

This is a graphical arrangement puzzle. Consider the following 36 tiles:

[image: Tiles]

Each tile has up to 8 *connected* directions and each tile has an initial *up* side. (The edge to whose centre the central pentagram points is the upper edge.)

These tiles have to be arranged into an arbitrary, single [polyomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) with a single restriction:

> **No tile may be placed such that a (brown) *connection* points directly at another tile that isn't pointing back.** 
> Note that it is possible to have a *connection* pointing at "nothing" (on the edge of the polyomino), but if it points at another tile, then that tile must have a *connection* pointing back.

The resulting polyomino is **scored** like this:

- Dissect the polyomino (however you wish) into smaller rectangles such that each tile is part of exactly one such rectangle.
- The number of *inner edges* in these rectangles - i.e. all edges which connect two tiles of the rectangle - are counted, and that number is squared.
- If any tile was rotated from its original position, a value has to be subtracted from your score: This value is the square of the total number of 90° rotations used (compared to the original tile-set.)  For example, if one tile was rotated clockwise by 90° and another by 180°, then the total number of 90° rotations is 3, and the penalty is $3^2=9$.
- **Bonus score:** Solutions which include all 36 tiles in a square are ranked by the number of 'separate networks' they form - the less networks the better, i.e. the ultimate solution additionally forms a single "brown" network.

> ### Find the highest possible score for this puzzle.
>
> (The tile-arrangement has to be shown.)

---

### Example of a *valid* arrangement (only 9 tiles):

[image: Valid]

As no tile was rotated, the score of this set is $7^2 + 1^2 + 0^2 = 50$
( A 2x3 rectangle has 7 inner edges, a 2x1 rectangle has 1 inner edge, a single tile has no inner edge. )

### Example of an *invalid* arrangement (only 9 tiles):

[image: Invalid]

The bottom-right corner tile points towards the central tile, which isn't pointing back.

### 2nd Example of an *invalid* arrangement (only 4 tiles):

[image: Invalid]

Both C4 and A4 point at a tile (the one diagonal below) which is not pointing backwards. (That they two 'link' with each other via the corner is not important.)

Comment: The most optimal solution would be to place all 36 into a single rectangle (of any dimensions), with no rotations. There is no guarantee that such a solution exists, but it is likely. One can write a program to find such a solution.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Sure, but the puzzle is to find it - or the next best if it is not possible.

Comment: The simplest program to find the perfect single rectangle would be about ten lines long, but the sun would die out before it tried all 7*36! possibilities.

Comment: @Kevin It's much more than that, remember the tiles can be rotated. so, there is a factor of $4^{36}$ there. The death of the sun is tomorrow considering that.

Comment: What does "pointing back" mean exactly? Is something [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ2nP.png) allowed?

Comment: @Sleafar, no it isn't. Thanks for the example. "Pointing back" means that the tile in direct direction of the link has a link which - again in direct direction - points to the origin. I'll add your image as 'not allowed'.

Comment: well at the point where I stopped because I have to also work sometimes when I'm at work.... (I think)   I easily had it 5x5 and messing around with the pieces to put it at 5x6. So I'm fairly certain the answer is going to be 5x6 + the rest. (It gets complicated fast from there to try and fit it to 6x6 so I doubt that solution exists, but I'm not there yet) - will post it tonight as coordinates.

Comment: Is there also a restriction that all tiles must be part of a single "network"? See Spacemonkeys comment below my answer. Neither of my solutions nor the 1*36 solution would work then.

Comment: @Anachor If we are looking for the perfect solution we can ignore rotation and any squares apart from 6*6. As soon as we place a single tile the number of tiles which can be placed next to it is very limited, so I think the number of possibilities is way lower. However, if that solution doesn't exist, the number of further possibilities gets bigger.

Comment: @Selafar: No, such a restriction does not exist. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 6x6 solution with 3 rotations: 3591

> 6x6 square = 1 bounding rectangle with 60 inner edges
>  3 total 90° rotations
>  $60^2 - 3^2 = 3591$ (*single network*)
>  [image]

Thanks again to Sleafar for the image!

Comment: Nice, looks like it's time to brute-force the rest, to see if there is a better option.

Comment: Very nice! I'll accept this unless a better solution comes about....

Answer (score 6):

### 6x6 solution with rotations: 3479

> $60^2 - 11^2 = 3479$ (single network)
> [image]

### Inkscape image

Not part of the answer, but I have created an [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) image which should make handling the tiles way easier. Download it from here:

http://imgh.us/polyomino.svg

For **snap** to work configure it like in the screenshot below (the three activated buttons near the right border):

[image]

Comment: Could you merge your non-answer and answer into one so that your answer doesn't get dinged for 'not an answer'?

Comment: Thanks for making a start. As I've had to change the scoring to avoid the trivial case, I've updated your values.

Comment: Does E6 and E1 work though? they aren't linked (non continuous)

Comment: @Spacemonkey These is only "a single restriction" in the question, and it doesn't forbid this AFAICT.

Comment: @Sleafar you are correct, I read the OP anew. I must have imagined that restriction while looking at the polyomino examples

Comment: Yes, this is a valid solution. There is no condition for a continuous network - although I wonder if I should add that as a bonus score :c)

Comment: Which I now have

Answer (score 2):

## 6x6 solution with rotations: 3404

> 6x6 square = 1 bounding rectangle with 60 inner edges
>  14 total 90° rotations
>  $60^2 - 14^2 = 3404$
>  [image: 6x6 polyomino solution]

A big thanks to [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar) for the Inkscape image! It made my life a *lot* easier when playing around with this.

Comment: Well done! The first to find a square - and manually (and before the end of the universe ;c) ) I wonder if anybody could beat it with less rotations..

Comment: As there could be more 6x6 solutions - even with the same point-score - I've added a bonus-score rule: If two 6x6 squares have the some point-score, the one with lesser 'separate' networks is superior.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable tie-breaker!

Comment: @BmyGuest 6*6 is not the only solution left. 4*9 with 8 rotations would have a higher score as well.